# Using "in that" instead of "in which"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, locative, pied-piping, that-vs-which

In this sentence:

> The diet could be prescribed for someone with any disease **in which** there is an abnormal retention of fluid.

Is it correct to replace "in which" with "in that"?

Where we could do that?

Are they interchangeable?

Can we put prepositions exactly next to "that" (as a relative pronoun)?

like this:

> He worked for a spy network **about that** I knew nothing.

Comment: I think you can't in the first one. — *which* is used for things, in this case for the *desease*. As for the second one, it doesn't make sense, but it would if you wrote *He worked for a spy nerwork which I knew nothing about.*

Comment: Would you give me and example in which they are interchangeable? or We can never use them instead of each other in pied-piping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*That* cannot head a relative clause when it is the object of a preposition which it directly follows—that is, when the preposition is 'pied-piped' with the relativizer to the beginning of the clause:

> He worked for a spy network about **<sup>∗</sup>that** I knew nothing. *This must be written using* which . . .
>   He worked for a spy network about **<sup>ok</sup>which** I knew nothing.

In ordinary speech, *that* can head a relative clause if the preposition is not pied-piped but 'stranded' in its original position:

> He worked for a spy network **<sup>ok?</sup>that** I knew nothing about.

Formal written English frowns on this; but formal written English frowns on stranding the preposition, too, although that's now far more common than it used to be.

And you should note that neither "rule" applies when the relativizer (*which* or *that*) is not the object of the preposition:

> He took off his hat. This is the hat **<sup>ok</sup>that** he took off.

In this case *hat* is **not** the object of *off* but the Direct Object of *take*, and *off* is ...

- well, there's a lot of argument about that. Traditional grammar calls it an 'adverb'. Some modern grammarians call it a 'particle', and others call it an 'intransitive preposition'. ***I*** call it a locative complement.

In any case, it is **not** a preposition governing the relativizer, whether that's *that* or *which*, so it **cannot** be pied-piped—

> This is the hat **<sup>∗</sup>off which** he took.

It must remain stranded in its original position.